# Using PowerShell's Where-Object -Filterscript with AWS EC2 Tags to filter resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, filtering

How can I use Where-Object -Filterscript to look up AWS resources based on Tag and corresponding tag value?

If I run a command to look at the tags:

```
(Get-Ec2Address -region $region).Tags
```

I receive an output like:

> Key                Value
>
> ---                    -----
>
> environment         dev
>
> project            project
>
> Name              blah

So if I want to look up all EIP resources where the project tag has a value which matches "project", how can I do that? I'm trying this:

```
 Get-EC2Address -region $region | Where-Object -FilterScript {
     $_.Tags.Key -match "project" -and `
     $_.Tags.Value -like "*$project*"
}
```

But that's just showing me the EIPs that have a key "project" and a value "project", not where the EIPs have the key of "project" and the CORRESPONDING value is "project".

For example,

```
Get-EC2Address -region $region | Where-Object -FilterScript {
     $_.Tags.Key -match "project" -and `
     $_.Tags.Value -like "*dev"
}
```

will still return a result, despite us having no projects called "dev"

How can I link those the Key and the Value when filtering?

Comment: FYI, I'm looking to achieve this using PowerShell filters rather than AWS filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it like this

```
Get-EC2Address -region $region | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Tags.Key -match "project"} | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Tags.Value -like "*$project*"}
```

I dont have an AWS env to test your code. This^^ is a little inefficient but should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sid. I tried the code, but it looks like it's matching an object which has a key called project and has a value which matches $project, but not necessarily where they key and value correspond.

Comment: Oh, I didnt pay enough attention to notice you were working with a hashtable. In hashtables, you are not going to have duplicate keys. (There will only be one key with the name Project). If you see, `$_.Tags.Project` , its value will be `project`. You don't even need to do a match. Essentially, `$_.Tags.<keyname>` will give `corresponding tag value`